# Stop iPhone notifications turning on the screen?

Tags: iphone

I have a fairly old iPhone so the battery isn't great. Im getting a lot of notifications which is depleting my battery quickly, I believe due to the screen turning on each time.

I'd still like to get a vibration for message notifications, and ideally be able to read the notification preview if I turn on the screen.

Can this be done globally rather than per app?

Comment: I don't know how you'd measure it, but I wouldn't be surprised if the buzzer used more power than the light. Have you experimented with Focus modes, or Do Not Disturb?

Comment: @Tetsujin do not disturb or focus mode would also prevent the buzz